# Create user with superuser privilege using Apache brooklyn

Tags: brooklyn

When a new VM is launched using Apache brooklyn , how can we create a login user with superuser/root privileges ?

The OS setup section in  https://brooklyn.incubator.apache.org/v/latest/ops/locations/ suggests using 'dontCreateUser ' . where can I find this configuration ?
 Should this be part of brooklyn.properties ? If yes, then how should this be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brooklyn will by default grant `sudoers` privileges to the created brooklyn user.

If you want to run as root directly, you can set

```
<location-prefix>.user=root`
```

and brooklyn knows not to create the user.  This can be set in `brooklyn.properties` (or in yaml set `user: root` in the location block or under `provisioning.properties` in the entity).  If you need a more explicit example just ask.